# Does Django support setting the beginning value for an id column?

Tags: django, database, model

I have seen several questions and answers on SO, most were three years old or older and I looked at the [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#bigautofield) (hoping I didn't miss it).  I have to have a 9+ digit number for an id.  Most responses were to do this at the database.  I am guessing that means to create the model in Django and then go back to the database and change the id column Django created with a new starting/next value attribute on the column.

If not how can I create a database table from Django, *Code First*, that allows me to create a table with an id column that starts at 100000000?  And, it be done with the stock model object methods in Django.  I don't really want to do a special hack.  If that is the case, I can go the database and fix the column.  I was trying to adhere to the Code First ideas of Django (though I prefer database first, and am afraid using inspectdb will make a mess.)

Edit:  I didn't want to use [UUID](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#uuidfield).  I believe [BigAutoField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#bigautofield) is best.

Comment: Do you want an ID that increments?

Comment: @EricBlum Yes.  Auto increment.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do this in two steps:

1 - Specify your primary key explicitly using `primary_key=TRUE` in your model definition. See the [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#automatic-primary-key-fields) for more info. You can then specify `BigAutoField` or whatever other type you want for the primary key.

2A - If you're populating the database up front, just set `pk: 100000000` in your fixture.

OR

2B - If you're not populating the database up front, use Django Model Migration Operations RunSQL as detailed [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/migration-operations/#runsql). For your SQL use `ALTER TABLE tableName AUTO_INCREMENT=100000000`.